# How do I handle any button's left-click with a single event handler function in C# instead of one for each button?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

Using the following :

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Button1" x:Name="btn1" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Button2" x:Name="btn2" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="output"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

How do I handle any button's left-click with a single event handler function in C# instead of one for each button?

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: To my knowledge, I don't think you can. If I'm understanding your question correctly, are you trying to add all the buttons in like a ButtonGroup and then assign the event handler to the group instead of the individual buttons? Because what you have currently is how you would handle your question. The button has to know about the event handler, and you need to specify it in order for it to know.

Comment: You tagged XAML but is this using WPF, Silverlight, Xamarin, etc.? That may affect the possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place multiple similar buttons inside stackpanel and don't want to write `Click="Button_Click"` everywhere then you can do it by next way.

1. Add `runat="server"` attribute to your StackPanel and add some ID, for example `ID="ButtonsContainer"`
2. Iterate by all controls inside your StackPanel:

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < ButtonsContainer.Controls.Count; i++) {
    var button = ButtonsContainer.Controls[i] as Button;
    if(button != null)
        button.Click += Button_Click;
}
```